# Code safety in C programming (avoiding any segmentation/errors)

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

lets say I have a linked list( any kind , let just say singly linked list)

```
  for(current = head; current!=NULL; current=current->next)
       free(current);
```

Let's say this is my code , is there going to be any point at which this code might fail? or is there a safer approach to free the nodes?

Comment: Aside from the obvious problem already pointed out in the answers below, it is almost always a good idea to use `{}` braces, even when you think you only have a single statement following the `for`. One day you decide to add another line... you indent it, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is certainly a problem with this code: the for loop you are executing is equivalent to

```
current = head;
while (current!=NULL) {
   free(current);
   current=current->next;
}
```

That is you are accessing `current` **after** the free.

You should change this to

```
current = head;
while (current!=NULL) {
   tmp = current;
   current=current->next;
   free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: No idea why this was -1 (save for the missing semicolons). It does much the same as my answer.

Comment: I prefer this approach - the `while` makes the code structure nice and clean.

Comment: @abligh : fixed the semicilons (I was just writing some Python ;-)

Comment: @hivert: my condolences.

Comment: I am very sorry, that -1 was a mistake click from me. I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unsafe as you do:

```
free (current);
```

then the `for` loop will execute:

```
current = current->next;
```

which evaluates `current->next` when `current` is free.

How about:

```
 for(current = head; current!=NULL;)
 {
     temp = current->next;
     free(current);
     current = temp;
 }
```

Also you can abbreviate that by:

```
 for(current = head; current;)
 {
     temp = current->next;
     free(current);
     current = temp;
 }
```

Comment: I would always recommend to test explicitly : `for(current = head; current != NULL;)` it is more readable. In general, I think that using a `for` loop in this way is ugly since there is no explicit "update loop counter" step. It's a matter of style, but in this case I think it's better use a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks alot I didnt notice that! Wow that was a small thing but it could have completely ruined my program. Jesus, i feel dumb lol

Comment: `valgrind` is your friend for catching these use-after-free errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at the following step:

```
current = head;
current != NULL
free ( current );
current = current->next;
```

Do you see a problem?  You are trying to go to `next` *after* `free`ing the memory allocated to `current`.

Comment: @user3100209 - it is better to thank people for answers rather than get all emotional at yourself. This is not the forum for using all caps.